# Future/Promise like stuff for Trio in Python?

Tags: python-trio

Say I have a class `Messenger` which is responsible for sending and receiving messages. Now I have a service that sends out requests and waits for responses via it, matching each pair with an id field in the message. In asyncio I would do:

```
class Service:
  ...

  async def request(self, req):
    new_id = self._gen_id()
    req.id = new_id
    fu = asyncio.Future()
    self._requests[new_id] = fu
    await self._messenger.send(req)
    return await fu

  def handle_response(self, res):
    try:
      fu = self._requests.pop(res.req_id)
    except KeyError:
      return

    fu.set_result(res)
```

So I could send out multiple requests from different tasks, and in each task wait for the corresponding response. (And some messages may not have a corresponding response that are handled in another way.)

But how do I do this in Trio? Should I create an Event / Condition / Queue for each request and put the response in a predefined place?
If yes, which is the best for this scenario? Or there is another way to do this?

Comment: Here's an issue on the trio bug tracker discussing the best way to handle this case and document it: https://github.com/python-trio/trio/issues/467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simple class that contains an `Event` and your result.

However, strictly speaking events are overkill because multiple tasks can wait on an event, which you don't need, so you should use `trio.hazmat.wait_task_rescheduled`. That also gives you a hook you can use to do something when the requesting task gets cancelled before receiving its reply.

http://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-hazmat.html#low-level-blocking

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple [`Future` class in aioresult](https://aioresult.readthedocs.io/en/stable/future.html). (Disclaimer: I wrote aioresult.) It is a tiny class with a `trio.Event` and the result or exception, but it saves a few lines of code compared to implementing it yourself.

```py
from aioresult import Future

class Service:
  ...

  async def request(self, req):
    new_id = self._gen_id()
    req.id = new_id
    fu = Future()
    self._requests[new_id] = fu
    await self._messenger.send(req)
    return fu

  def handle_response(self, res):
    try:
      fu = self._requests.pop(res.req_id)
    except KeyError:
      return

    fu.set_result(res)

async def use_service(service, req):
    response_future = service.request(req)
    await response_future.wait_done()
    print(f"for {req} got {response_future.result()}")
```